# Использование регулярных выражение в sed команде для редактирования файла

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash, sed

Есть конфиг file.json В нём прописывается куча разных параметров. Среди них прописаны координаты некоего места - LATITUDE и LONGITUDE.
Координаты могут иметь следующий вид:

- X.XXXX
- XX.XXXX
- XXX.XXXX
- -X.X
- -XX.XX
- -XXX.XXX

Где X - это некоторая цифра. Минус вначале может присутствовать или нет, в зависимости от полушария. Цифр может быть вначале от одной до трёх, а после точки - произвольное количество.

Пример:

```
"LONGITUDE" : -12.34,
```

Менять руками эти координаты достало и я решил написать себе шаблон sed-команды, используя регулярки, но проблема в том, что оно не работает =)

```
sed -i '/LONGITUDE/s/-?\d+\.\d+/-0.1234567/' file.json
```

Моя логика при написании команды:

1. Ищу все строки с вхождением слова LONGITUDE
2. Ищу в этой строке вхождения типа "минус есть/нет (я никогда не знаю, есть ли он), не менее одной цифры, точка (она есть всегда), не менее одной цифры"
3. Заменяю это вхождение на конкретную цифру с минусом (Хотя, могу и без минуса. Дело случая)

Уже прыгал с бубном вокруг этой команды, редактируя эту регулярку, но ничто не хочет менять мне необходимое значение на необходимое значение. Ткните меня носом в мою ошибку, пожалуйста, и помогите найти правильный вариант.

Comment: Попробуй флаг -r. По умолчанию в sed регулярки не pcre, а posix.

Comment: Пробовал флаги -ir / -ri / -r / -i / -i -r
Безрезультатно

Comment: А если `[0-9]+` вместо `\d+`?

Comment: `sed -i -E '/LONGITUDE/s/-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/-0.1234567/' file.json`: 1) `\d` не поддерживается, 2) Используйте POSIX ERE, если нужен квантификатор `+`.

Comment: sed -i '/LONGITUDE/s/-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/-0.1234567/' file.json --- Безрезультатно

sed -i -E '/LONGITUDE/s/-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/-0.1234567/' file.json --- Консоль ругнулась sed: invalid option -- E

sed -iE '/LONGITUDE/s/-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/-0.1234567/' file.json --- Безрезультатно

Comment: Попробуйте использовать утилиту **jq** для работы с файлами **json** из коммандной строки или из скриптов bash.

Comment: Какая ОС, версия sed, FreeBSD или GNU?

Comment: OS - QNX /// sed --version 
GNU sed version 4.1.5

Comment: Странно. Должно работать как я написал, но можно и `sed -i '/LONGITUDE/s/-\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}/-0.1234567/g' file.json`

Comment: Ой, маменьки, а вот последний вариант работает. Спасибо =))

Comment: А так работает? `sed -ir '/LONGITUDE/s/-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/-0.1234567/' file.json` или `sed -ir -e '/LONGITUDE/s/-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/-0.1234567/' file.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цифровой шаблон `\d` не поддерживается в `sed`.

Кроме того, вы используете POSIX BRE, в котором `?` и `+` означают именно эти знаки и не являются квантификаторами.

Если использовать POSIX BRE, решение выглядит так:

```
sed -i '/LONGITUDE/s/-\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}/-0.1234567/g' file.json
```

где

- `[0-9]` - цифра
- `\{0,1\}` - ноль или один повторов (`?` в POSIX ERE)
- `\{1,\}` -  ноль и более повторов (`+` в POSIX ERE)

Согласно [документации QNX](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_utilities%2Fs%2Fsed.html), для активации поддержки POSIX ERE нужно использовать `-r`.

```
sed -ir -e '/LONGITUDE/s/-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/-0.1234567/' file.json
```

Comment: Очень частный случай. *тут шутка про регулярные выражения*